# Google Client API can't read property 'people' although it is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-api, coffeescript, google-api-js-client, google-people-api

I am trying use [Google Client API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) to access some User data for a contest with Coffeescript.

So far I successfully accessed the data with the first signin with this code:

```
initSignIn= () ->
  gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient)

  # Init click function for sign in button
  $('#signin-button').on 'click', (e) ->
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
    return false
  return


initClient= () ->
  # Init the client API
  $.when(
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: 'AIzxxx',
      discoveryDocs: ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"],
      clientId: '31xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scope: 'profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
    })
  ).then(
    # Add listeners for sign in changes
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen( updateSigninStatus )
    updateSigninStatus( gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get() )
  )
  return


 updateSigninStatus= (isSignedIn) ->
  # If the user is signed in then make the call for getting the user data
  if isSignedIn then makeApiCall()
  return


makeApiCall= () ->
  # Test logs
  console.log "gapi.client"
  console.log gapi.client
  console.log "gapi.client.people"
  console.log gapi.client.people

  # Getting the user data
  gapi.client.people.people.get({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names,person.email_addresses',
    requestMask: {
      includeField: 'person.names,person.email_addresses'
    }
  }).then(
    (response) ->
      apiCalled = false
      console.log(response);
      console.log('Hello, ' + response.result.names[0].givenName)

      return
    (reason) ->
      apiCalled = false
      console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message)
      return
  )
  return
```

When I refresh the browser I still get the data some of the times. But often it seams that the "people" property can't be loaded. I printed out the client object in the console and right after it printed out the people property. It showed me the client object with the people object in it, but the next line it could not read the people object anymore:

[image: Console logs of API call]

Am I doing something wrong here? It is the first time I am using the client API. Thanks for your help!